# Remove spaces between two inner ```<td>``` elements

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var str1 = "78896541230";
str1 = str1.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'x');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str1;
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="maintable" class="maintable">

  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" id="PageHeadingTable">
        <tr>
          <td id="PageHeading" nowrap="true">OTP Verification</td>
          <td id="PageHeadingDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="//faml/request/datetime" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td height="100%" valign="top">
      <div class="y_scroll" id="contentarea" style="width:98%;position:absolute">
        <!--y_scroll start-->
        <div class="contentarea">
          <!--contentarea  start-->


          <span id="box" class="box"> <!--rounded curve/border  start-->
          <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
          <div class="middlepanel">         
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="formtable">
           
          <caption>Confirm your identity</caption>
         <tr>      <td>A One Time Password(OTP) has been sent to your mobile phone with number ending in </td><td id="output"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr ><td  > If this is not your mobile number, you are advised to end your internet banking and call us</td>
           </tr>
          
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          </div>
         
          </table>
          </div>
          <div class="bottompanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
     
         </span>

        </div>
        <!--contentarea  end-->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to make an OTP page where user can input the recieved OTP on the screen.Since I have masked the user's phone number for security reasons. I am getting the value of masked phone number in seperate `<td>`. The only problem is there is a space between my two `<td>`. I am not sure how to remove the space since its nested. I have added the code in the snippet for better understanding of my problem.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks!!

Comment: not able to understand which space it is. Please add different border color to each of the `td` to clarify the question

Comment: Not sure which tds are the problem. However, at one point you have `</div>` before the `</table>`. Which isn't valid HTML.

Comment: ```<td>```A One Time Password(OTP) has been sent to your mobile phone with number ending in ```</td>``` . Check after this

Comment: If you need the masked number to directly follow the "...with number ending in..." phrasing you should keep them in the same table cell, don't separate them. Move the `#output` element to the first `td` and make it an inline element like a `span`

Comment: I did that.Provided the first ```td``` the ```#output``` element but then the whole phrase was replaced by the masked number.

Comment: Shouldn't replace the table cell content - unless you added the id `output` to the table cell `td` itself. Just cloned your snippet and tested it as I suggested - worked just as expected. The id selector should be placed on an empty inline element nested in the table cell, e.g: `<span id="output"></span>`

Comment: I tried adding the id ```output``` in span too. It misplace from its original place. Can you provide me an answer for the same. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2rzb47k5/

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much. I wish i can upvote your comment but I am unable to since I have low reputation her. Again thanks very much :)